# What does the ASCII art on the Amazon Linux 2 AMI MOTD mean?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

When logging in to an Amazon Linux EC2 instance, one is greeted by the following MOTD:

[image: Amazon Linux MOTD]

What does this ASCII art try to convey?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just assume part of the ASCII-art chars have been made invisible, whereas if you would in-hide them all it would look (more or less) like so:

```
 ____   ____   ___
| ___| /  __| /_  )
| _|   | (     / /
|____| \____| /___|
```

I trust it’s clear then what the answer to your question actually is:
<kbd>**EC2**</kbd> … Get it now?

Comment: I'm not sure why you thought my [suggested edit](https://devops.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/11788) should be rejected, please note https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379084/how-to-apply-special-formatting-within-a-question-s-title-e-g-to-highlight-a-k#comment1265175_379084.